# Flex working on web but not mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code:

```
<li class="new">
    ...
    <div id="left-content">
      <span id="right" class="btn btn-primary label">0</span>
      <span class="btn btn-primary label">0</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

The two `span` elements that I have appear centered when previewing my website on my desktop with Chrome (i.e: the top and bottom margins are the same relative to the `li` they are contained in).

However, when viewing on mobile Chrome and mobile Safari, the two `span` elements 
appear at the top of the `li` rather than centered how I'd like them to be.

I believe that this has to do with the `flex` and `flex-box` properties in my code but I have checked compatibility and I've also used an [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to make sure that the CSS would be cross-browser compatible but it still appears to cause the same issue.

Here's a link to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kwcwyzb4/4/ (edited)

Comment: Which "mobile" are you using? (OS/Browser/Version)

Comment: iOS 9.3.1 (Browsers specified above - same result in Chrome and Safari).

Comment: safari and chrome versions?

Comment: @Dekel both at latest

Comment: @NotToBrag I see that you have given margins for the flex children (`preview` element)... some flexbox implementations have issues with margin... just a hunch that you should check that first...

Comment: @kukkuz Removing all margins from the `preview` elements still results in the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kwcwyzb4/4/

Comment: removing the CSS for the `#left-content` element creates the same effect when viewed from both web and mobile so I'm guessing that the problem is there, but all the prefixes should work and flexbox should be compatible with my mobile browsers. Could anyone test this?

Comment: Try adding `position: relative; margin-left: auto;` to your `#left-content`.

Comment: @Senthe still doesn't appear to work: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwcwyzb4/19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here are `align-items` and `justify-content` properties set for `#left-content` element.

You set them both to `left` which is not even a correct value for those properties. Possible values are:

`align-items: stretch|center|flex-start|flex-end|baseline|initial|inherit`

`justify-content: flex-start|flex-end|center|space-between|space-around|initial|inherit`

In this case you should set:

`align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;`

More about flexbox properties: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also, you should replace `#left-content`, `#right` and similar `id`s with classes. If you have two or more elements with the same `id` on the same page it can cause all kinds of bugs. It's strongly recommended to stick to classes for styling purposes.